# Lint is unable to catch RHS and LSH width mismatch

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, lint, register-transfer-level

Below piece of logic is doing 2^(3+x), where x is 2 bit value and can have max 2'b11, according to the below logic, RHS will be 1 << 6, which is 7'b1000000. MSB will be discarded as LHS is of 6 bits.
Checked this code in Spyglass Lint, VCS compile elab, Synthesis results etc, couldn't find any violation. Is there a tool that can find mistakes like below?

```
module module_test (
  input  wire [1:0] x,
  output wire [5:0] y
);

assign y = 6’d1 << (3 + x);

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is discarding some or *all* the bits of a value when shifting is a perfectly valid thing to want to do. A static linting tool checker is not designed to catch all possible functional bugs.

If you had an assertion that `y` must always have a one-hot value, then a formal property checker can statically determine that the result could be 0 and generate a violation. Assertions are what you use to capture design intent, and either a static formal tool or dynamic simulation tool can catch differences between intent and what got implemented in RTL.

Comment: Thanks, agree formal property verification can catch this bug. I am still curious to know, what lint tool takes to find out this kind of bug. Do you agree that lint should be capable enough to find a mentioned bug at least?